# Connecting Azure SQL Server PASS DB

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I'm using SSMS to connect to Azure DB from my laptop. I have provided my laptop IP address in "Set server firewall". However, each time when connecting from SSMS it's considering my public IP address, instead of laptop IP.

My questions are:

1. why is it not considering my Laptop IP?
2. How safe is it to configure a public IP address in Azure's "set server firewall"? Will not it possible someone having same public IP can able to connect to Azure DB?
3. How the Azure DB can be configured so that it should account the request from my laptop IP only?

Comment: This is a fairly broad set of questions. For #1, it's difficult to know what's going on, as there's not enough detail. Did you choose your laptop's IP address while connecting to the Azure portal via the same laptop, and did you choose your current address as the one to add (the portal specifically offers this)? For #2: This seems opinion-soliciting - not sure how it can be answered here. For #3, there is plenty of documentation about private endpoints and virtual networks that cover this. All that aside: this isn't really a programming question, more of a service configuration/networking one.

Answer (score 0):

To help you answer these questions, we first must consider the network topology involved. Your laptop is likely connected to a wireless access point which is connected to a network switch. All traffic on the switch (or series of switches depending on the location you are at) uses a private IP addresses to communicate. These addresses **cannot** be routed on the public internet. In order for you to access the Azure SQL Database which sits on a different private network then your laptop, it had to travel over the public internet. This means your traffic is going through a series of routers and in order for the connection to correctly route between you and Azure, it needs your public IP address.

It is safe to a certain point. The Azure SQL Server you are connecting too uses SSL/TLS to encrypt the traffic so communication over the public web is encrypted. Your concern for essentially spoofing the public IP is valid which is why it is crucial to make sure you have selected a strong password for the SQL login. Microsoft also deploys a series of edge security services that monitors for attacks on any of their services to ensure the safety of their platform and will flat out block suspected attacks.

If you want to restrict traffic so that only your laptop can be used, now we are introducing a complex but doable architecture. You will need to setup a VNet and VPN Gateway in Azure and connect the two services. You will have to then connect the Azure SQL Database to the VNet you just setup. Once completed, you will need to access the VPN from your laptop which will grant you access to the database. The actual setup isn't trivial as there are many things to take into consideration such as cost, hardware capabilities on your side and security requirements.

At the end of the day, what should drive the "right solution" should be your security requirements. For some, running via a public IP is sufficient, for others they need to access it over a VPN.

To address your comment below, I needed more space so I'm amending the solution.

Anytime you make something publicly accessible over the internet, there is a possibility for someone else to access it. The chances are lowered the more complex you make the password to the resource. If you do not have a static IP address for your internet or someone spoofs your public IP address, there is a chance an attacker will have the ability to connect to the Azure SQL Server. This is where the password complexity comes into play. The stronger the password, the harder/longer it will take to brute force their way in.

If you have time to do the research/learning on this, I'd suggest taking a look at the online training Microsoft has for the Azure Solutions Architect certification. I think it will help you to better understand the intricacies involved with building a solution such as this.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/certifications/azure-solutions-architect

Comment: Sorry, I got little bit, what you said. But, didn't get to the point answer.Please note, the data security is must. Will someone having same ISP / service provider can be able to connect to Azure dB - considering current scenario?

Comment: Please don't use an answer to promote specific consultants or certifications. This isn't the place for that. Plus, the notion of "is it safe enough" is a broad, opinion-soliciting question (and not a programming question), and isn't on-topic here - there's simply no right way to answer it. SQL Database networking options are well-documented as well (virtual networks, private endpoints, IP-based firewall...).

Comment: It was not my intention to promote consultants or a specific certification, so I do apologize if it came across that way. I was just trying to suggest using the free training Microsoft has to help fill potential knowledge gaps on how the services work.

Answer (score 0):

Azure PaaS service has a public endpoint, so it means that you cannot connect to them from your private IP, you must configure your Azure PaaS with your public IP. There is an option to make a public endpoint as a private endpoint using a private link, vpn point to site, virtual network gateway. Please, have a look at this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-private-endpoint-overview) for more details.

[image: private endpoint]

You can keep security your connection from public IP using Azure PaaS firewall once your connection from your source to azure allows only you public IP, but you have to change this IP in firewall for each time your IP is renewed in case it is dynamic. For the best practice you should consider a private link or a Azure Instance Manager SQL which has more option, but it is more expensive then Azure PaaS SQL.